# How to concatenate a row and column in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an `1xN` cell matrix of strings `Let={'A'} {'B'} {'C'}...{N}` and a `Mx1` matrix of doubles `Num=[2;4;6;7;10...M]`. I would like to concatenate each of the strings with each of the doubles + additional characters to create an `MxN` array of the form

```
LetNum=
{'A-2*'} {'B-2*'}...
{'A-4*'} {'B-4*'}...
.
.
.
```

I can use a `for` loop with `strcat`, but is there a quicker way?
I was able to use `repmat`:

```
LetNum=strcat(repmat(Let,size(Num,1),1),"-",repmat(string(Num),1,size(Let,2)),"*")
```

However, the code can get lengthy as `Let` and `Num` are themselves wordy calls to data stored in other array. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 1x1 character arrays inside a 1xN cell array. Strings are introduced in R2016b and a different thing. If you have ≥ R2016b, you can use the strings and implicit expansion like this:

```
LetNum = cellstr(string(Let) + '-' + Num.' + '*');
```

If you have ≥ R2017a, you can initialise strings with `" "`. This will make it even shorter:

```
LetNum = cellstr(Let + "-" + Num.' + "*");
```